# in wireguard there is no access to some dns

Tags: vpn, docker, wireguard

I am implementing a docker with wireguard on a Linux ubuntu20.04 server as it says in its official documentation at https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-wireguard The clients cannot access certain websites, I get an error like the following: Access Denied You don’t have permission to acces Does anyone know why this happens with the default configuration of the official docker?

Comment: How does your docker-compose or docker run look like

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure `PEERDNS=auto` by default it uses the DNS server of the host but you can try to put in a public dns like 1.1.1.1 in there

```
---
services:
  wireguard:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/wireguard:latest
    container_name: wireguard
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_MODULE #optional
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Etc/UTC
      - SERVERURL=wireguard.domain.com #optional
      - SERVERPORT=51820 #optional
      - PEERS=1 #optional
      - PEERDNS=1.1.1.1 #optional
      - INTERNAL_SUBNET=10.13.13.0 #optional
      - ALLOWEDIPS=0.0.0.0/0 #optional
      - PERSISTENTKEEPALIVE_PEERS= #optional
      - LOG_CONFS=true #optional
    volumes:
      - /path/to/appdata/config:/config
      - /lib/modules:/lib/modules #optional
    ports:
      - 51820:51820/udp
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to use different DNS, either 1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8 or even leave the value in auto, and I still cannot resolve some websites through the VPN. I’m going to leave one of the websites that don’t load for me as an example, in case someone wants to reproduce the error: https://www.zara.com/ and this is the configuration that I’m launching in Ubuntu server 20.04 and 22.04 environments, as indicated in the linuxserver repository with the following configuration:

> docker run -d 
> --name=wireguard 
> --cap-add=NET_ADMIN 
> --cap-add=SYS_MODULE `#optional` 
> -e PUID=1000 
> -e PGID=1000 
> -e TZ=Etc/UTC 
> -e SERVERPORT=51820 `#optional` 
> -e PEERS=1 `#optional` 
> -e PEERDNS=auto `#optional` 
> -e INTERNAL_SUBNET=10.13.13.0 `#optional` 
> -e ALLOWEDIPS=0.0.0.0/0 `#optional` 
> -e PERSISTENTKEEPALIVE_PEERS= `#optional` 
> -e LOG_CONFS=true `#optional` 
> -p 51820:51820/udp 
> -v /etc/wireguard/config:/config 
> -v /lib/modules:/lib/modules `#optional` 
> --sysctl="net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1" 
> --restart always 
> lscr.io/linuxserver/wireguard:latest

Comment: Please edit the original question and add this new information in it instead of as an answer.